# how to cache images with node.js

Tags: node.js, wordpress, express, caching

I am creating a node.js server with express. The user can save the WordPress templates code in the database and can reuse it for later. The problem is when the user can use images in their templates.

Sample short code of Wordpress:

```
<!-- wp:image {"id":123,"width":245,"height":436,"sizeSlug":"large","className":"is-style-rounded"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large is-resized is-style-rounded"><img src="http://gutenbergforms.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/mobile-1.png" alt="" class="wp-image-123" width="245" height="436"/></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->
```

Now in the shortcode above. There is an image used in the code. I want to get the image and create a cache in the server so that everyone who uses this shortcode can view the image. Currently, I am using base64 encoding for the image.

Comment: :-)   dear bro, upvote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60470549/6877799) not the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, for caching something like you said, there are three ways:

- Cache it from WordPress:

  Use a WordPress cache plugin, like: `WP Super`, `WP Rocket` and etc.
- Cache it from Node:

  Use a caching tool like `express-cache-tool`
- Cache it by using in-memory tools:

  Use some tools like [`redis`](https://redis.io/)

For having better help, descript more about your issue.